# Why viewmodelfactory not recognizing in my project?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-viewmodel

I am developing an android app using ViewModel but I am getting following error below my project[viewmodelfactory error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8HYA9.png).

below my ViewModel implementation

```
import android.app.Activity
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelStoreOwner

fun <T : ViewModel> Activity.obtainViewModel(viewModelClass: Class<T>): T {
    val todoRepository = (this.application as TodoApplication).todoRepository
    return ViewModelProvider(this as ViewModelStoreOwner, ViewModelFactory(todoRepository)).get(
        viewModelClass
    )

}
```

I want to know where I am causing an error.

below what I have tried

```
import android.app.Activity
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModel
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelProvider
import androidx.lifecycle.ViewModelStoreOwner

fun <T : ViewModel> Activity.obtainViewModel(viewModelClass: Class<T>): T {
    val todoRepository = (this.application as TodoApplication).todoRepository
    return ViewModelProvider(this as ViewModelStoreOwner, ViewModelProvider.Factory.get(todoRepository,
        viewModelClass
    ))

}
```

and getting following error  Type mismatch: inferred type is ViewModelProvider but T was expected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/lifecycle/ViewModelProvider) `ViewModelProvider` constructor takes two parameters. The second one is `ViewModelProvider.Factory`. Replace `ViewModelFactory(todoRepository)` with an instance of `ViewModelProvider.Factory`

```kotlin
fun <T : ViewModel> AppCompatActivity.obtainViewModel(viewModelClass: Class<T>): T {
        return ViewModelProvider(this).get(viewModelClass)
    }
```

Comment: I am getting following error Type mismatch: inferred type is ViewModelProvider but T was expected

Comment: @NicollaGallazzi can you explain what you have told with coding sample

Comment: @HackerOne please cut and paste your code and the error in the question